I am currently trying to implement the `printNewEdition` method while `prepend` priority fee and `blockhash` ` , err on `confirmTransaction` ,?
Create edition builder(); err: The transaction could not be confirmed TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError
const editionBuilder = await metaplex
  .nfts()
  .builders()
  .printNewEdition(editionParams, {
    commitment: "finalized",
  });

editionBuilder.prepend({
  instruction: ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({
    microLamports: 600000,
  }),
  signers: [],
});

const { blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight } = await metaplex
  .rpc()
  .getLatestBlockhash();
const editionTx = await editionBuilder.toTransaction({
  blockhash,
  lastValidBlockHeight,
});

const signers = [metaplex.identity(), ...editionBuilder.getSigners()];

const signedEditionTx = await metaplex
  .rpc()
  .signTransaction(editionTx, signers);

const base58SignedEditionSig = base58.encode(
  signedEditionTx.signatures[0].signature
);

  const confirmResponse = await metaplex
    .rpc()
    .confirmTransaction(
      base58SignedEditionSig,
      { blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight },
      "finalized"
    );

